# form_for and form_tag parameters for custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, form-helpers

I would like to use a `drop` action in the friendships controller to drop requests of friendship, and I am struggling to understand how to create a working form and working routes.

I added the following route in `config/routes.rb`

```
resources :friendships, only: [:create, :destroy] do
  member do
    post :drop
  end
end
```

This would generate the named route `drop_friendship_path(id)`. 
My question is now how to create a working form, that is what parameters am I necessarily required to use with `form_for` or `form_tag`.

Since in view I would iterate on `@users` requesting a friendship, I would not know the id of the request to delete, so I cannot use the above named route. Which one of the following is correct?

```
<%= form_for(current_user.friendship_request.find_by(requester_id: user.id), url: { action: drop }) %>

<%= form_tag({controller: "friendships_controller", action: "drop"}) do %>
```

I struggled to find documentation on parameters to use with `form_for` and `form_tag`. The [api documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) says that the `:url` 
argument for `form_for` may be represented in the same way as values passed to `url_for` or `link_to`. So for example you may use a named route directly. Documentation on `url_for` or `link_to` however does not add anything else.

I found only examples, not an exhaustive documentation, in the [form helpers section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) of guides.rubyonrails.org for [form_for](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object) and [form_tag](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#multiple-hashes-in-form-helper-calls), so I realized that `url` for `form_for` can have a hash of subparameters (however only `action` is reported) , and that the `controller` and `action` parameters can be passed to `form_tag`.

What is the complete list of parameters for the `url` hash in the `form_for` helper? 
What is the relative list of parameters for the `form_tag` helper? 
Which ones are required in my form?

If, instead of specifying controller and action, I used inside form_for or form_tag:

```
url: drop_friendship_path(@friendship_request)
```

and defined `@friendship_request` in the `drop` action, would that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way is to use `button_to` or `link_to` helpers for your purpose. `button_to` generates a form. `link_to` generates a link, but can also send post request with `{method: :post}` option.

Why do you think you can't use the `drop_friendship_path(id)` helper method? You can:

```
<% request_id = current_user.friendship_request.find_by(requester_id: user.id) %>

<%= button_to "Drop", drop_friendship_path(request_id) %>
<!-- or -->
<%= link_to "Drop", drop_friendship_path(request_id), method: :post %>
```

Why don't you use the existing `destroy` action to delete friendships instead of `drop` ?

And also, sending a separate query for each user to get a friendship record is not a good thing. You should think of how you can avoid this. There are many solutions, but it is not the subject of the question.